# The issue of Alamofire getting data with parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, parameters, alamofire

I use `Alamofire` to get data from the server,but I can't get any data when I use the parameters method，while it can get with the complete url(including 2 parameters in the url ).
The url format:`http://mobilecdnbj.kugou.com/new/app/i/search.php?cmd=302&keyword=%E5%88%98%E5%BE%B7%E5%8D%8E`. 
The 2 parameters, one is `cmd` = 302 , another is `keyword` which needs user to input.

I used the 2 following methods to get data, but only the `method 2` can get data:

**Method 1:**

> let Search_Recommendation =
>   "http://mobilecdnbj.kugou.com/new/app/i/search.php"

```
func getSearchRecommendation(keyword:String,success succeed:@escaping([String]) -> Void,failure fail:@escaping ((NSError)) -> Void){

        var recommendations = [String]()
        let parameters = ["cmd":302,"keyword":keyword] as [String : Any]
        let headers = ["Content-Type":"Application/json"]

        Alamofire.request(Search_Recommendation, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

            /** the following code is the same in the 2 methods*/

            if let json = response.result.value as? JSON{
                if let data = json["data"] as? [JSON]{
                    recommendations = data.map({
                        return (SearchRecommend.init(json: $0).keyword)!
                    })

                }
                succeed (recommendations)
            }else{
                fail(NSError())
            }

        }


    }
```

**Method 2:**

> let Search_Recommendation =
>   "http://mobilecdnbj.kugou.com/new/app/i/search.php?cmd=302&keyword="

```
 func getSearchRecommendation(keyword:String,success succeed:@escaping([String]) -> Void,failure fail:@escaping ((NSError)) -> Void){
    var recommendations = [String]()

    let url :String = Search_Recommendation + keyword.URLEncode()!

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in

            if let json = response.result.value as? JSON{
                if let data = json["data"] as? [JSON]{
                    recommendations = data.map({
                        return (SearchRecommend.init(json: $0).keyword)!
                    })

                }
                succeed (recommendations)
            }else{
                fail(NSError())
            }

        })

 }
```

**URLEncode Method:**

```
  func URLEncode() -> String? {
            //self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
            return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ").inverted)
        }
```

**I wonder why the method 1 can't get data?How to solve it? Thanks.
Any point is appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

Look like you use the wrong encoding. In order to have append parameters to the `URL`, suppose to be using `URLEncoding.default`.

Replace this:

```
Alamofire.request(Search_Recommendation, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
```

With this:

```
Alamofire.request(Search_Recommendation, method: HTTPMethod.get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
```

`JSONEncoding` actually append the parameters to the `body` instead of `url`. Therefore, your server is unable to process it. Using the above, you will not need method two anymore.

The [example and documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#url-encoding) by Alamofire is quite clear, maybe you like to read more about the differences.